# Update UILabel on UITextInput change (Xamarin)

Tags: c#, xamarin, events, xamarin.ios

I have UILabel at my View and UITextinput.

I need to write smth at text -input and change this text at label "live".

For example for button it will be like

```
 yourLabel.Text = "Init";
buttonExample.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) => {
    yourLabel.Text = "I touched my button";
};
```

How I can do it for text-input?

Thank's for help.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous can you explain in short what exactly do you want.

Comment: I have text-input at View and label. When I type smth in tex-input, I need to update label "live @G.hakim"

Comment: So you have used the TextInput protocol on a view and on an update of that view you want to update the label? Correct me if i am wrong

Comment: have you tried `EditingChanged` EventHandler?

Comment: Yes. You're right @G.hakim

Comment: Did you try using `ValueChanged` handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the text of UILabel when you editing the textfield.You can implement it by adding target on the textfield.Refer the following code.

```
...
using ObjCRuntime;
...

 //add target on your input
 textField.AddTarget(this,new Selector("TextFieldDidChange:"),UIControlEvent.EditingChanged); 

...
[Export("TextFieldDidChange:")]
void TextFieldDidChange(UITextField textField)
{
   // do something you want
   yourLabel.Text = textField.Text;
}
```

> Note:the text of label will changed in real time with the text of input